# Geocoder stopped returning shapes

Tags: here-api

I was using IncludeShapeLevel on geocoder for a while now, but suddenly it stopped returning Shape value.

The article is still in the documentation and even the example is not working.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/example-geocode-retrieve-shape-area.html

My request
`https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json?apiKey=${hereApiKey}&searchtext=${postCode}+Czech+Republic&additionaldata=IncludeShapeLevel,postalCode`

Thank you

Comment: It works for me (see https://anatolysukhanov.com/images/here.png)

Comment: Still doesnt work for me, maybe its related to plan? Im on freemium. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Soo, the answer is DONT use API key for javascript. It used to work, but now you need to use REST API key. With REST api key it works like it used to.